# Not able to access environment variables with spring.config.import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-parameter-store

I have used spring.config.import feature to import values from AWS parameter store in my springboot application. But not able to access the imported values in my service class. Please help.

In aws param store, I have below values:

```
/config/my-project/preset/onboarding = app,scan,shop
/config/my-project/preset/onload = redeem,notification
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - "optional:aws-parameterstore:/config/my-project/preset"
```

In my Java class, trying to access env variables:

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Component
public class DataService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public MemberData getPresetData(final String preset) {
        
        log.info("preset => " + preset);         /* preset = onboarding */

        String fields = env.getProperty(preset);
        
        log.info("fields => " + fields);         /* fields prints as null */
   
        String fields = env.getProperty("/config/my-project/preset/onboarding");
        
        log.info("fields => " + fields);         /* fields prints as null */
    }
}




build.gradle =>

springboot version 3.1.1

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.0.3'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-parameter-store:3.0.1'
implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager:3.0.1'
```

Comment: I recently experienced a problem that spring.config.import did not work at all (no effect) except the case when it is used in application.properties file

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael Gantman. In my case, i can't use application properties file, as I need to read specific parameter from parameter store based on the incoming request. Eg: The incoming request comes with request param "onboarding", then I need to read parameter store to get value of "/config/my-project/preset/onboarding"

Comment: And how do I print all the properties available in "Environment" instance. Just so I can see if at all any of my other parameters are in there.